# Newbie question - where do I find the php file for the desired link?

Tags: uri

I hope my question is asked properly since I have been seriously looking for about 2-3 hours how to find the php file to the url on the drupal website.

Lets say the url is www.example.com/profile/account

Where do I find profile.php or how do I know the name of the php file in order to edit it?

If someone gets offended by my post being too "lazy" its not true, I am exhausted of looking and I might be totally dumb but I cannot seem to understand where to find it.

ANY help is appreciated

Comment: drupal doesn't really work that way. what are you trying to change on that page?

Comment: I will try to explain it the best I can. Currently you can book meetings. If you want to book 5 days, you will have to repeat the procedure 5 times. I want to make it possible to book as many dates as you want without having to repeat any procedure. But I cant even find the file to start editing anything, its very confusing and I just got assigned to this job

Comment: @J.Doe I think, instead of asking for php file, you just post your real question/challenge and what you want to do in your site. So, here people first will let you know  what is the right way to do that. May be you are thinking that it can be done just changing the php code, but solution can be something different with Drupal.

Comment: The Drupal profile form doesn't have anything on it related to booking meetings out of the box - that must be functionality provided by a custom or contributed module. First step is finding out what that module is, and how it's been set up, then take baby steps to learn the various Drupal apis that you need to use to alter it. You need to know have at least a basic knowledge of how Drupal works to have any hope IMO, and it's a very broad subject, so I'd advise getting stuck into some general Drupal tutorials before you get stuck straight in to the specific task

Comment: If you want a visual representation of learning Drupal: https://web.archive.org/web/20160507042856/http://www.codem0nk3y.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/cms-learning-curve.png . I wish I was joking

Comment: @J.Doe Yeah, the straight answer to your question is that there isn't a profile.php file; drupal uses it's own routing system instead of depending on the file structure. Drupal 7 uses one method (http://mikecr.it/ramblings/how-drupal-7-works-part-3-the-router), drupal 8 uses a different one (https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/routing). You can find an intro to Drupal 8 routing here (https://www.drupal.org/node/2116767)

Comment: I have found where to edit pages now :) and its possible to export the code to php, so perhaps I can ask a new question soon with more details, I did not know of this until now. Nonetheless I thank you all for your honest input and I appreciate it alot. @the last picture: haha dont scare me bro I just started using it

Comment: @J.Doe Please answer your own question if you want and select it as answer, so this question doe snot pop-up by the system as unanswered. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is basically that Drupal is more oriented towards modules and interface rather than raw coding, so editing a site is most likely not going to be the regular procedure of finding a file with the name of the link. However, to understand Drupal, which is not too hard, you just have to try try try and fail until you make it.

I am still new and dont get much, but I am starting to understand how to edit different things. My new obstacle is understanding how groups work, which I have 0 idea about, but thats the new challenge!

Hope this helped someone "understand" Drupal abit better. If im wrong, anyone is welcome to correct me or edit my post.

Wish you a happy friday